# React navigation not showing the right screen

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have created a navigation setup for my application that should start off with a welcome screen on the welcome screen you find two buttons, one for registering and the other for logging in.

When the user registers or logs in he get sent to other screens. I have created a stack navigator between the log in and register screen and put them in a loginFlow constant and another between the welcome screen and the loginFlow constant and the navigation between these screens works, but for some reason the welcome screen doesn't get shown first instead I get the sign up screen (register screen).

Why is that the case and how can i make the welcomeScreen get shown first

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import WeclomeScreen from "./app/screens/WelcomeScreen";
import MainScreen from "./app/screens/MainScreen";
import AccountScreen from "./app/screens/AccountScreen";
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from "./app/context/AuthContext";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import SignupScreen from "./app/screens/SignupScreen";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import ResultShowScreen from "./app/screens/ResultShowScreen";
import ResolveAuthScreen from "./app/screens/ResolveAuthScreen";
import SigninScreen from "./app/screens/SigninScreen";
import ArticleSaveScreen from "./app/screens/ArticleSaveScreen";
import { setNavigator } from "./app/navigationRef";

const articleListFlow = createStackNavigator({
  Main: MainScreen, // screen with diffrent articles categories
  ResultsShow: ResultShowScreen, // article details screen
});
const loginFlow = createStackNavigator({
  Signup: SignupScreen,
  Signin: SigninScreen,
});
loginFlow.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerShown: false,
  };
};

articleListFlow.navigationOptions = {
  title: "News Feed",
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <View>
      <Icon style={[{ color: tintColor }]} size={25} name={"ios-cart"} />
    </View>
  ),
  activeColor: "#ffffff",
  inactiveColor: "#ebaabd",
  barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#d13560" },
};
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  ResolveAuth: ResolveAuthScreen,
  MainloginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    WelcomeScreen: WeclomeScreen,
    loginFlow: loginFlow,
  }),

  mainFlow: createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      articleListFlow: articleListFlow,
      ArticleSave: ArticleSaveScreen, // we dont need this one
      Account: AccountScreen,
    },
    {
      activeColor: "#ffffff",
      inactiveColor: "#bda1f7",
      barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#6948f4" },
    }
  ),
});
const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App
        ref={(navigator) => {
          setNavigator(navigator);
        }}
      />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

here is the content of ResolveAuthscreen :

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Context as AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

const ResolveAuthScreen = () => {
  const { tryLocalSignin } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    tryLocalSignin();
  }, []);

  // not returning anything since just waiting to check the token
  // will transition to signin or signup very quickly
  return null;
};

export default ResolveAuthScreen;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the content of the `ResolveAuthScreen` also?

Comment: yes i added it in my initial post

Comment: And what is in the `tryLocalSignin` function?

Comment: just a way to see if the user login information is stored on the local device so he can signin automaticly without having to enter the login info each time

Comment: Are you navigating the uses in the `tryLocalSignin` function on the basis of any condition?

Comment: here is the code i used for it 

`
 // AUTOMATIC SIGNIN ONLY USING TOKENS ON USER DEVICE
const tryLocalSignin = (dispatch) => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    // if token exists
    dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: token });

    navigate("Main");
  } else {
    // if token doesnt exist
    navigate("Signup");
  }
};
`

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your comments, you have an issue in your `tryLocalSignin` method. In that method, if there is no any `token`, you are navigating the user to the `Signup` screen. Instead of navigating to the `Signup` screen, navigate to the `WelcomeScreen` screen like:

```
const tryLocalSignin = (dispatch) => async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: token });
        navigate("Main");
    } else {
        navigate("WelcomeScreen");
    }
};
```